# How do I convert a C# byte array into structured data?

Tags: c#, struct

I am passing 64 byte data packets over USB to a microcontroller. In the microcontroller C code the packets have the structure,

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char data[CMD_SIZE];
    cmd_get_t get;
    // plus more union options
} cmd_t;
```

with

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char cmd;          //!< Command ID
    unsigned char id;           //!< Packet ID
    unsigned char get_id;       //!< Get identifier
    unsigned char rfu[3];       //!< Reserved for future use
    union
    {
        unsigned char data[58];     //!< Generic data
        cmd_get_adc_t adc;          //!< ADC data
        // plus more union options
    } data;                     //!< Response data
} cmd_get_t;
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
    int16_t supply;
    int16_t current[4];
} cmd_get_adc_t;
```

On the PC side in C# I have been provided with a function which returns the 64 byte packet as a Byte[]. The function uses Marshal.Copy to copy the received data into the Byte[] array. I then used a C# struct of the form

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
    public struct COMMAND_GET_ADC
    {
        public byte CommandID;
        public byte PacketID;
        public byte GetID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]
            public byte[] RFU;
        public short Supply;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
            public short[] Current;
    }
```

and again used Marshal.Copy to copy the byte array into the struct so that I could work with is as structured data, e.g.

```
COMMAND_GET_ADC cmd = (COMMAND_GET_ADC)RawDeserialize(INBuffer, 1, typeof(COMMAND_GET_ADC));
short supply = cmd.Supply;
```

with

```
public static object RawDeserialize(Byte[] rawData, int position, Type anyType)
{
    int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(anyType);
    if(rawsize > rawData.Length)
    {
        return null;
    }
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    Marshal.Copy(rawData, position, buffer, rawsize);
    object retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, anyType);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    return retobj;
}
```

This just feels like I am making lots of copies of the data and like it might not be the most productive way of achieving what I want to. I also need to convert the structured data back to a byte array for commands to the device. I have a method which uses the same process (i.e. use a struct and then serialise it to a byte array and pass the byte array to the write function).

Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use unsafe code, you can cast the byte array to a pointer to your structure using the 'fixed' keyword.

Comment: In the code base I am working from the class is declared unsafe (to allow interaction with the Win32 USB HID dll's). So yes, I suppose I could. I just need to figure out what the implications and hazards of unsafe are. I was avoiding it because I don't fully understand it yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling native dll yourself you could define your DllImport-s so they return and accept COMMAND_GET_ADC directly - provided that you have structs represented correctly. The framework itself should take care of it.

If you have to use byte array mandated by usage of methods provided to you - then I don't know, I never had such a constraint. I always tried to represent my interoperability data in the same way as in native dlls and I don't remember I had major issues with that.

EDIT:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct COMMAND_GET
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte CommandID;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte PacketID;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte GetID;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]
    public byte[] RFU;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ADC_Data Adc_data;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public SomeOther_Data other_data;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    ....
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct ADC_Data
{
    public short Supply;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public short[] Current;
}
```

Basically where you have FieldOffset(6) you're creating union like data union in cmd_get_t

Comment: I don't follow you 100%. I need to first check the first byte (command ID) and then map the data to the appropriate struct. How would this fit in with your proposed solution? Could you give some sort of simple example (or point me to one)?

Comment: I actually tried this but for some reason the thread appears to just crash when the LayoutKind is set to explicit and I use the MarshalAs for the arrays. I haven't figured it out yet. Thanks for the example.